# Bash need to check if multiple pid exist

Tags: bash, centos

The script that I'm building needs to check if more process (pid) are running of the same process. If the process ran twise we need to kill this process.

Here is a example, for some reason this process will run twice. So we need to monitor this and need to kill / restart the mono process.

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

set -x                          # set debug
PID="/usr/local/bin/Serverd.pid"
Service="/etc/init.d/serverd" $1

#
# Functions
#
die (){
   printf '%s\n' "$*" >&2
   exit 1
}

log(){
   logger -t HealthCheck -i $*
}

process () {
   [[ $(pidof mono /dev/null 2>&1) == '' ]] && echo 0 || echo 1
}

pid () {
   [[ ! -r $PID ]] && echo 0 || echo 1
}

for i in $(process); do
   if [[ $i -eq '0' ]]
   then
      echo 'Process is Stoped!!!!!'
      if [[ $(pid) -eq '1' ]]
      then
         echo PID still there, remove PID first
         rm -rf $PID
         $Service start
         exit 1
      else
         $Service start
         exit 1
      fi
   else
      echo 'Process is Running!!!!'
      exit 1
   fi
done
```

If I have 2 PID of the same mono process this need to be killed

```
+++ pidof mono /dev/null
++ [[ 30454 30014 == '' ]]
```

How cat I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your issue is that `pidof` returns a list of multiple pids, and you wish to kill them all.

If that's the case, you could do:

```
pids=($(pidof mono))
for pid in ${pids[@]:1}; do
    kill -9 $pid
done
```

This:

- Puts the pids in an array
- Gets a subarray not containing the first element
- Kills each of the items in that subarray.